# Объединение таблиц

Tags: mysql, проектирование

Имеется несколько лендинг-страниц, на которых показывается по несколько рекламных баннеров. Серфер (юзер) приходит на лендинг и кликает по баннерам.
Есть в MySQL базе 2 таблицы статистики (агрегированные по некоторым полям). Статистика по приходам на лендинги и кликам на баннеры. Таблица входа (*report_in*) - отображает статистику приходов серферов на лендинг-страницы, таблица выхода (*report_out*) - статистика кликов по этим баннерам.
Упрощенный DDL.

[image: Упрощенный DDL.]

Получается серфер приходит, записывается +1 показ в текущий день в таблицу *report_in* по соответсвущему ID лендинг-страницы. Когда кликает на баннер, то в *report_out* записывается связь на report_in, день и +1 клик по нажатому ID баннера.
Таким образом, мы видим сколько пришло юзеров на лендинги и сколько было сделано кликов по их баннерам.

Могут возникать следующие ситуации:

- юзер пришел на лендинг и ничего не кликнул (т.е. есть запись в *report_in*, но нет в *report_out*)
- юзер пришел на лендинг и нажал на несколько баннеров (т.е. есть запись в *report_in* и на нее ссылается несколько записей из *report_out*).

Как в результате объединения, получить такую таблицу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь получается, что на лендинге #5 находятся баннеры #10, #11. На этот лендинг пришло 100 пользователей и кликнули по 20 и 30 раз соответственно на баннеры 10 и 11. А вот на лендинг #6 пришло 50 пользователей и ни разу не кликнули по баннерам.

Приджойнить *report_out* к *report_in* нельзя, потому как продублируются записи report_in, а эта таблица нужна для дальнейшего агрегирования (например, сгруппировать по лендингам и месяцу и посчитать сколько пришло и ушло по баннерам).

Это что-то типа FULL JOIN получается. Пока что в голову пришла идея только через UNION:

```
SELECT 
date AS DATE,
landing_id AS LANDING_ID,
count_impressions AS LANDING_IMPRESSIONS,
NULL AS BANNER_ID,
NULL AS BANNER_CLICKS
FROM report_in

UNION

SELECT
NULL AS DATE,
NULL AS LANDING_ID,
NULL AS LANDING_IMPRESSIONS,
banner_id AS BANNER_ID,
count_clicks AS BANNER_CLICKS
FROM report_out
```

Но как-то костыльно. может есть какой-то более правильный путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cделайте обычный left джоин. Группировке это не помешает. Надо группировать сначала по дата-ID_лендинга и при этом берете max(кол-ва приходов), при этом параллельно спокойно считаете sum(кол-во кликов),count(id банера) потом оборачиваете это все еще одним select и догруппировываете уже до требуемого

```
select landing_id,sum(LANDING_IMPRESSIONS) as LANDING_IMPRESSIONS,
       sum(BANNER_CNT) as BANNER_CNT,sum(BANNER_CLICKS) as BANNER_CLICKS
  from (
        select I.date AS DATE, I.landing_id AS LANDING_ID,
               max(I.count_impressions) AS LANDING_IMPRESSIONS,
               count(O.banner_id) AS BANNER_CNT,sum(O.count_clicks) AS BANNER_CLICKS
          from report_in I left join report_out O on O.id_report_in=I.id
         group by I.date,I.landing_id
       ) A
 group by landing_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM Report_in inner join Report_out on Report_in.id = Report_out.ID_REPORT_IN;`
Вместо * можете перечислить поля которые вам нужны.

Comment: так я не получу записи из *report_in*, у которых нет связи с *report_out*. Т.е. лендинги, которые были показаны, но никто не кликнул на из баннеры.